# Trying to add JSON data inside of erb tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, erb

> I am trying to place JSON data inside of a Rails "link_to" tag using Angular ng-repeat to later access using "@date". As of now the "@date" is not getting populated with the "blog.date" data. I know there is conflict because of the client/server side difference, so wondering if this is even possible, or maybe a better way to resolve?
>
> HTML

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="blog in blogs | only<%= @month %>_<%= @year %> | xFutureDates">

      <p class="default_blogArchives_date">{{blog.date}}</p>
      <p class="default_blogArchives_title">{{blog.title}}</p>
      <p class="default_blogArchives_description">{{blog.description.trunc(150)}}<%= link_to("Read More", :action => "show_page", :date => "{{blog.date}}") %></p>

  </li>
</ul>
```

> Controller

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end


  def show_month
    @month = params[:month_id]
    @year = params[:year_id]
  end

  def show_page
    @date = params[:date]
  end

end
```

Comment: move the logic to angular and only use server as data api like most people do